# How to run apk file on mac to test phonegap app?

Tags: android, phonegap-build

I need to test my android phonegap app. I have the APK file and have tried to get some sort of android emulator running on my mac with no luck. i just need to test the app for android but cant get it to work. i have the android sdk manager installed but cant find the right commands for it to run an apk file in x location.

the phonegap emulator doesnt seem to work for apk files, by the looks of it, it runs html, css, js files on an iphone size screen. unless im doing something wrong and it can work apk files.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download android studio and the Android SDK, run the emulator and send the apk to your email, in the emulator accessing your mail and download the apk, install it and test ...